# Delete every occurrence of Nil in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, comparison

At university we received the task to write a function

`> deleteNil :: Tree a -> Tree a`

that is deleting every occurrence of Nil in a Tree of the type

`> data Tree a = Nil | Leaf a | Br ( Tree a ) ( Tree a )`.

If the Tree contains nothing but Nil the returned value should also be Nil.
The only restriction is that neither the type signature of Tree nor the signature of the function deleteNil is allowed to be edited, e.g. I am not allowed to append
`deriving Eq, Show`
to the type signature of Tree a.

My first try to solve this problem was as follows:

```
> deleteNil :: Tree a -> Tree a
> deleteNil Nil = Nil
> deleteNil (Br l r)
>        | deleteNil l == Nil && deleteNil r == Nil = Nil
>        | deleteNil l == Nil && deleteNil r /= Nil = r
>        | deleteNil l /= Nil && deleteNil r == Nil = l
>        | deleteNil l /= Nil && deleteNil r /= Nil = Br l r
```

But obviously because I am not allowed to derive Eq this version gives me the compiling error

`No instance for (Eq (Tree a)) arising from a use of '=='`.

I don't want to ask for a complete solution of this problem here, but has someone a new approach for me how I should try to solve this problem without having to compare parts of the tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you almost got it right, what you are missing is that you can pattern match on `l` and `r` too:

```
deleteNil :: Tree a -> Tree a
deleteNil Nil = Nil
deleteNil (Br Nil Nil) = Nil
deleteNil (Br   l Nil) = (deleteNil l)
deleteNil (Br Nil   r) = (deleteNil r)
deleteNil (Br   l   r) = case (deleteNil l, deleteNil r) of
    (Nil, Nil) -> Nil
    (nl, Nil) -> nl
    (Nil, nr) -> nr
    (nl, nr) -> Br nl nr
```

Be careful to also consider the `Leaf` option in your function.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I'll try this lead for now and post an update in about an hour or less :)

Comment: Wow, your template was pretty awesome: All i had to do was to append `> delNil (Leaf a) = Leaf a` to make this work as intended, thanks! Unfortunately I have no 15 reputation to upvote this great answer, but you should be sure I would and will once I reach them.

Comment: @JoeCocker Glad I could help. You should accept and/or upvote the answer to show its usefulness to other people, unless you feel like you can formulate an even better answer, in which case you should post it.

Comment: Righty, I forgot that I am also able to accept an answer, not only to upvote it, my bad :) catched up with it now :)

Comment: @user3237465 Right, I fixed it

Comment: This seems like it ought to generate an infinite loop in the final case?

Comment: Should be ok now, as I used user3237465's version.

Comment: So I need to create another recursion in order to make him take the pattern `deleteNil (Br Nil Nil)` to return Nil. I will try to modify that in the existing code instead of wrapping it up from the beginning. Status update following soon. EDIT: checked your upated code, is there a way to write this down without the usage of `case of`?

Comment: @JoeCocker This is the quickfix, as it was important for me to get the code working, I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern-matching:

```
deleteNil :: Tree a -> Tree a
deleteNil (Br l r) = case (deleteNil l, deleteNil r) of
    (Nil, dr ) -> dr
    (dl , Nil) -> dl
    (dl , dr ) -> Br dl dr
deleteNil  t       = t
```

So you do not need four cases, since this two

```
| deleteNil l == Nil && deleteNil r == Nil = Nil
| deleteNil l == Nil && deleteNil r /= Nil = r
```

are actually this one:

```
| deleteNil l == Nil = deleteNil r
```

because it should be

```
| deleteNil l == Nil && deleteNil r /= Nil = deleteNil r
```

since you want to return a tree, that doesn't contain `Nil`s.

Also, you can provide an instance for the `Eq` typeclass:

```
instance Eq (Tree a) where
    Nil      == Nil      = True
    Br l1 r1 == Br l2 r2 = l1 == l2 && r1 == r2
    _        == _        = False
```

Comment: Your answer is leading to the correct output, but it is pretty much stuff included we never spoke about before (I'm learning Haskell since not even 2 months). Our tutor will most likely ask me about the usage of "instance Eq" or "case ... of" if I use this solution. Still a great idea and most likely useful for someone else who uses the search function for a similar problem.

Comment: @Joe Cocker, case-expression is just a way to use pattern-matching without defining a function, so you can fix this by providing an auxiliary function.

Comment: Actually, If a tree is defined as ``Nil | Br (Tree a) (Tree a)``, you can simply do ``deleteNil _ = Nil``, since all elements can only be ``Nil``. ``Tree a`` then becomes something like ``Proxy a`` from [``Data.Proxy``](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.2.3.1/docs/Data-Proxy.html).

Comment: I want to emphasize that Leaf is already implemented (see `> data Tree a = Nil | Leaf a | Br ( Tree a ) ( Tree a )`)

Comment: @Joe Cocker, that's clear. I've chosen this representation of `Tree` to make the `deleteNil` function total. Ok, I've switched to your definition of `Tree` to remove ambiguity.